# Buliding an Organization Structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

MY application is build With Nodejs , Atlas Mongodb DB and Express
for user Authentication Im using PassportJS.
for the DB connection I Use Both Mongoose and MongoClient
Im Looking forward to Split my Application Structure to Many Organizations

Up until Now I had Only One Organization - Which has its Own users Controlled By Him ,
3 layers of Credentials..

1. Admin
2. Shift Manager
3. Users
   Im Interested By Expanding My application to have Many Organizations , And for this I need an Isolated DB for each Organization
   Based on Authentication - user will connect to his organization and view only data coming for this organization (Based on His Inner Org Credentials..)

My Approach Was to create a function that will execute when user enters the "Login Post Request"
The function will find In each Org based on the req.body - username written
and Connect to the correct DB(Org) where this user belongs to .

Problems with this Approach :

1. same username's across DBS
2. Very bad for Performance
3. the DB connection is Applicational level so if a user is connected to ORG 1 , and a different User associated to ORG 2 tries to connect , the first user will be kicked off because the Application is now Connected to DB2 (ORG 2 ) - This Problem can be solved by Database Sessions ,
   I will Be happy for Any Help with this .

Here is My code :
The Function that I Created above the login route to Determine Which Organization The User Belongs to :

```
let dbName
let isConnected
async function findUser(req) {
   isConnected = false
   var client = new MongoClient(MongoUrl)
   try {
      await client.connect()
     let db1 = client.db('test')
     let db2 = client.db('test2')
   let db1collection =  db1.collection('users')
   let db2collection =  db2.collection('users')
   let searchdb1 = await db1collection.findOne({username: req.body.username})
   let searchdb2 = await db2collection.findOne({username: req.body.username})
   if (searchdb1) {
      dbName = 'db1'
      console.log(searchdb1)
   }
   if (searchdb2) {
      dbName = 'db2'
      console.log(searchdb2)
   }
   searchdb1 = null
   searchdb2 = null
   } finally {
      await mongoose.connection.close()
        //  MongoDB Connection
        if (dbName === 'db1') {
         await mongoose.connect(gym1, 
            { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .then(()=> {
            console.log('DB Connection, Successful')
            isConnected = true
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error connecting DB')
            console.log(err)
        })
        }
        if (dbName === 'db2') {
         await mongoose.connect(gym2, 
            { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
        .then(()=> {
            console.log('DB Connection, Successful')
            isConnected = true
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error connecting DB')
            console.log(err)
        })
        }
     }
      dbName = null
      await client.close()
   }
```

login Post request Route :

```
.post(catchAsync(async function(req, res,next) {
   await findUser(req).catch(console.error);
   await passport.authenticate('local',async function (err, user, info) {      
      if (err) {
         //  return res.status(401).json(err);
          req.flash('error',`${err}`)
      }
      if (user) {
       req.login(user,function(err){
         if(err){
            // return next(err)
            req.flash('error',`${err}`)
            res.redirect('/login')
         }
          req.flash('success', ` ${req.body.username} ,Welcome back`)
          const redirectUrl = req.session.returnTo || '/';
          delete req.session.returnTo;
          res.redirect(redirectUrl);
       })

      } else {
         //  res.status(401).json(info);
         req.flash('error',`${info}`)
         res.redirect('/login')

      }
  })(req, res,next)
}))
```

I Know My Approach is Bad And This is the Reason That Im Asking for a Better Approach For this kind of Application Structure
I Will Be Happy for Tool and Tips that are Relevant for MY Issue
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use a multi-tenant architecture with separate database connections per tenant (organization). Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Store organization information and the associated user credentials in a central database
   Create a central database to store organization information and user credentials. This can help avoid duplicate usernames across organizations and simplify user authentication.

Schema example:

```
// Organization schema
const OrganizationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  connectionString: String,
});


// User schema
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  organization: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Organization',
  },
});
```

2. In the central database, store a reference to the organization's specific database connection string
   Store each organization's specific database connection string in the connectionString field of the Organization schema.
3. When a user logs in, authenticate them using the central database and retrieve the organization's database connection string
   Authenticate users with the central database and retrieve the organization's database connection string after successful authentication.

   ```
    // User authentication route
    router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

    if (!user) {
      // Handle user not found
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    const isPasswordValid = await user.verifyPassword(req.body.password);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      // Handle invalid password
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid password' });
    }

    // Retrieve organization information
    const organization = await Organization.findById(user.organization);

    // Store the organization's connectionString for use in subsequent requests
    req.session.connectionString = organization.connectionString;

    // Successful authentication
    res.json({ success: true })} catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' })}});
   ```

By following this approach, you can authenticate users more efficiently and maintain separate database connections for each organization. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You Very Much For your Super Explained Answer This is so much appreciated ! I Will Try This Approach And Let You Know if this Would help ! I'm Pretty Sure it Will

Comment: Hey again @Arsalan Habib, I Would Be thankful if you can see my new post as a continue to this post Thanks ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76145117/multi-tenant-mongoose